# Joomla 1.5->2.5 menus missing

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I upgraded my website from Joomla 1.5 to 2.5.4, however, the menus seem to have disappeared. I was using a 1.5-only template previously, but the jUpgrade process has defaulted to pre-installed templates which is fine - but no menus! I've tried installing a few random other templates but all have the same issue.

FWIW most of the menu links are broken but I fixed a couple just to check, but no joy. The migrated site is still in its subpath which is I assume why components themselves aren't working.

As best I can tell, I followed the instructions in the Wiki on the Joomla site.

Any ideas? Thanks.

http://www.simsig.co.uk - original site

http://www.simsig.co.uk/jupgrade - migrated site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jUpgrade does not transfer the menu items from 1.5 to 2.5 properly. Those have to be recreated.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause is that the menus were displayed in module positions specific to the template you were using in Joomla! 1.5 and that your Joomla! 2.5 template doesn't have matching positions. Alternatively the migration process didn't update the menu module positions properly and it's looking for the positions in a specific template.

Open `Extensions->Module Manager` then from the Filter options select `Type->Menu` to see just a list of menu modules. Check the positions they're assigned to by opening the menu module and selecting a position by actually clicking on the "Select Position" button and clicking on the right position in the currently used template.

To help make the choice easy you can filter down the options by selecting your current template from the pop-up menu in the top right of the "Select Position" lightbox that opened when you clicked "Select Position".

Comment: That seems an eminently sensible suggestion, yet it doesn't work in this situation! As it happened, the template didn't have any non-"position-X" labels anyway but I've tried reassigning all the menus randomly to other positions with no joy. About all I could see different was that there was space left on the left for one of the menus - but no menu. Now I've tried other templates and positions and can't get even the spaced out one back again!

Comment: I tried creating a new menu. Guess what? It appeared! I compared it to the other menus and I couldn't see any setting that was different. I guess it's time to recreate the menus.

Comment: We've hit this before I realised it "looked OK" but you actually have to select the position and save the menu module then they should appear.  Did you try actually saving the modules?

Comment: I have the same problem, but creating a new top menu did not worked out for me.